# Use a different directory for the homepage without switching DocumentRoot

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I am switching from a Wordpress blog to a Hugo blog. I'd like to switch the content at example.com to display the content from /var/www/new-blog. It currently just displays the content in /var/www/. I would like to keep it in the new-blog directory and still have it be the what is displayed at the root of my website.

I do not want to change the DocumentRoot however as I have other directories in /var/www/ that I don't want to affect.

Do I need to use mod_rewrite to accomplish this?

Comment: `Alias` might do the trick (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html).

Comment: @Nic3500 I can't seem to get it working. Is something like `Alias "/" "/new-blog"` not how it should be?

Comment: @Nic3500 I did an alias `Alias "/" "/var/www/new-blog"` and instead of displaying the content at the location the root is listing the contents in new-blog. However going right to example.com/new-blog serves the page correctly.

Comment: @Nic3500 Error log states I am hitting the max amount of redirects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I understand from your post.

**Current situation**

Directory structure:

```
1) /var/wwww/
2) /var/www/new-blog/
```

1) `DocumentRoot /var/www/`
   So http://example.com/ points to /var/www

2) Reachable via http://example.com/new-blog

---

**What you want**

- http://example.com/ replies with content from /var/www/new-blog/
- http://example.com/SOMEDIRECTORY replies with content from /var/www/SOMEDIRECTORY/

---

**Solution**

At quick glance, I though `Alias` would do the trick, but not after I tried it myself.

So use mod_rewrite (make sure mod_rewrite is loaded).

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/$ http://example.com/new-blog [R,L]
```

This way, `http://example.com` or `http://example.com/` will both redirect to the new-blog directory.

Any other request (i.e. `http://example.com/dir`) will reply the content from `/var/www/dir`.

One thing to note, users will see their address bar change from http://example.com/ to http://example.com/new-blog.

---

**EXTRA Solution**

If you do not want your users to know they are being redirected, you could proxy instead.

First make sure `mod_proxy` and `mod_proxy_http` are loaded.  Remove the RewriteRule added prior, add this configuration instead:

```
ProxyPassMatch   ^/$ http://example.com/new-blog
ProxyPassReverse ^/$ http://example.com/new-blog
```

---

What is nice is that either solution will let you access files or directories under /var/www.  Only `http://example.com/` is redirected or proxied.

Comment: Thanks, that was a great answer to my question. You understood my question correctly. I went with the mod_rewrite option simply because clicking any link on the page would mean you end up at the /new-blog link. I'll try to fix this by regening my static site using `/` as the directory instead and see if that fixes it to allow mod_proxy to work well :).